# MySQL automated back up on Win Server

Tags: mysql, windows

What is the best method for automating the task of backing up a MySQL DB on a Windows 2003 Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a scheduled task that does:

```
mysqldump --user=blah --password=blah databasename > c:\somebackupfile.sql
```

Then you can have some normal backup software or process to backup that file.